# Can't compile in Texmaker "Sorry, but pdfLaTeX did not succeed"

Tags: errors, miktex, texmaker

When working on a university project we use Texmaker as our editor. We share our documents and compile our master in a dropbox folder. Now when I try to quickbuild the master document I get this message: 
 
 [image: screenshot]

The log file looks like this:

```
2016-02-26 10:58:32,049+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Invalid argument: path="*.aux"

2016-02-26 10:58:32,049+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Info: path="*.aux"

2016-02-26 10:58:32,049+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\File\win\winFile.cpp

2016-02-26 10:58:32,049+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 418
```

The only thing that have changed since last semester, is the different folders. 
I have Texmaker 4.5 and MiKTeX 2.9

Edit: I can still build the old project from Google drive, but I can't build the new project from dropbox.

Comment: Just to rule out texmaker, can you compile the rapport from the command line?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that? From the command prompt? And then the directory C:\Users\Andreas Nouoruzi\Dropbox\P2\Rapport  ? And what then? And thanks for the reply

Comment: `pdflatex Rapport.tex`

Comment: I'm not used to using commandopromt. When i start, it says C:\users\Andreas Nourouzi> 
Should i then write:
C:\Users\Andreas Nouoruzi>\Dropbox\P2\Rapport pdflatex Rapport.tex or
C:\Users\Andreas Nouoruzi>C:\Users\Andreas Nouoruzi\Dropbox\P2\Rapport pdflatex Rapport.tex?

Comment: @AndreasGrøndahlNourouzi after you open the prompt you have to type `cd Dropbox\P2\Rapport` to change the directory and then you run `pdflatex`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When i run it in commandopromt I get the same message as in Texmaker

Comment: Exactly what error. The error you have stated so far does  other make much sense.

Comment: I get these messages in comandoprompt http://imgur.com/LLqTDu0 @daleif

Comment: That does not help much, do you mind posting the log file?

Comment: I did post the text from the log file in the thread, but here it is again       
2016-02-26 13:39:09,064+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Invalid argument: path="*.aux"


2016-02-26 13:39:09,064+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Info: path="*.aux"


2016-02-26 13:39:09,064+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\File\win\winFile.cpp


2016-02-26 13:39:09,064+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 418

Comment: That is not the log. Latex produces a full log file, I'd like to see that file in its entirety

Comment: I don't know the rules of this forum, but here is a download link to the log file. If you want me to share it differently, just send a message. And thanks for your time. I appreciate it a lot. http://www.filedropper.com/rapport

Comment: Hmm, cannot read that on my tablet. BTW have you tried updating miktex, both as admin and user? Miktex sometimes behaves in odd ways (I haven't used it for years)

Comment: Yes. I have tried to reinstall both Texmaker and MikTex several times. I have tried to synchronize the repository. I have tried the running the Update MikTex. Nothing worked

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Interesting, the log file is incomplete. Just for "fun" try adding a `\end{document} ` and recompile, and move it around. Everything after that comnand is ignored (in inputted or included files you can also use `\endinput ` thus might be able to tell us if it is something in the document that makes pdflatex puke, for example a corrupt image.

Comment: It worked. Someone from mu study group had written \input*{} and it made pdflatex puke. But only for me, so that was strange.

Comment: For what it's worth: I am seeing pretty much the same error. I tried running it at the command prompt but didn't succeed, apparently because the file name contained a space. I renamed the .tex file to a name without spaces and the error was gone. It's very strange though, because this error started happening while I was frequently recompiling versions of the same file in order to trace a latex-error. At some point pdflatex would not compile the file any more (as described by the OP), even when I reverted back to a file version that previously worked. Makes no sense.

Comment: UPDATE: It's got nothing to do with the space in the name. pdflatex will accept other names with spaces. But it refuses the original name as an "Invalid argument: path="original filename.pdf" Interestingly it is not complaining about the tex-file but the pdf output. So I checked the directory and found indeed that the output-file with that name did not exist. Instead, I found a file with named "original filename-surface.pdf". I have no idea where that "surface" suffix comes from, except that that is the name of my computer.

Comment: UPDATE2: Since the file is on Ondrive, I suspect that Ondrive somehow got confused with the many new versions and renamed the file by adding the name of the computer. (Not that this makes any sense to me, just speculating). In any case, the timestamp of that file is exactly the time when the pdflatex error started occurring. So there is definitely a link between the strange naming and the pdflatex error. I tried deleting the wrongly named pdf file but pdflatex continues to complain the same way. So in short: it looks like that particular filename is somehow "burned" and cannot be used anymore.

Comment: Really strange, I've just seen something similar with a Mac user using university onedrive. It kept making the aux file size zero, so references and citations kept not working. Disabling onedrive sync made things go back to normal. Scary stuff.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved in comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got *almost* this error (slightly different):

```
INFO  pdflatex - starting with command line: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\PDFLaTeX" --max-print-line=16384 --synctex=0 --c-style-errors --interaction=nonstopmode MyFile.tex
FATAL pdflatex - Invalid argument: path="MyFile.pdf"
FATAL pdflatex - Info: path="MyFile.pdf"
FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\File\win\winFile.cpp
FATAL pdflatex - Line: 493
```

For me the cause of this error was another program having the PDF file open.

Closing the program fixed the issue.